# React table can't global filtering on custom column

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a react table. In the table some columns shows multiple data. How to global filtering properly?

```
const Table = ({ columns, data }) => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    setGlobalFilter,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    useGlobalFilter,
  );
```

data

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Id',
        accessor: 'id',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: (d) =>
            <span className='label'> {d.label} - {d.name} </span>
      },
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: (d) =>
            <span className='label'> {d.label} - {d.name} </span>
      },
```

]);

In above example filtering only works for id column. Label and name columns are not filtering. How to fix that?